# Cron job every 5 minutes before 30 minutes

Tags: cron, cron-task

I am trying to create a cron job that fires every 5 minutes before 30, for example:
10:25,
10:55,
11:25,
11:55 etc. I tried `*/25,55 * * * *` but this also sends messages at 10:50 and I'm not sure why, what would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the following, which is simply "[at minute 25 and minute 55](https://crontab.guru/#25,55_*_*_*_*)":

```
25,55 * * * *
```

In your original attempt, the expression `*/25` means "every 25th minute". As such, it would execute at 25 minutes after the hour, and then 25 minutes later.. or 50 minutes after the hour.